# limiting filter length in regex

Tags: php, regex

Here I have regex, in which I want it to filter only word length >8 and <15 characters. I added

`(?=.{8,14})b$`

[REGEX-http://regex101.com/r/sA5xL5](http://regex101.com/r/sA5xL5)

but it does not make any diff.

```
`^(?=.{8,14})b$\(?(?:(?:0(?:0|11)\)?[\s-]?\(?|\+)44\)?[\s-]?\(?(?:0\)?[\s-]?\(?)?|0)(?:\d{2}\)?[\s-]?\d{4}[\s-]?\d{4}|\d{3}\)?[\s-]?\d{3}[\s-]?\d{3,4}|\d{4}\)?[\s-]?(?:\d{5}|\d{3}[\s-]?\d{3})|\d{5}\)?[\s-]?\d{4,5}|8(?:00[\s-]?11[\s-]?11|45[\s-]?46[\s-]?4\d))(?:(?:[\s-]?(?:x|ext\.?\s?|\#)\d+)?)$^|^2(?:0[01378]|3[0189]|4[017]|8[0-46-9]|9[012])\d{7}|1(?:(?:1(?:3[0-48]|[46][0-4]|5[012789]|7[0-49]|8[01349])|21[0-7]|31[0-8]|[459]1\d|61[0-46-9]))\d{6}|1(?:2(?:0[024-9]|2[3-9]|3[3-79]|4[1-689]|[58][02-9]|6[0-4789]|7[013-9]|9\d)|3(?:0\d|[25][02-9]|3[02-579]|[468][0-46-9]|7[1235679]|9[24578])|4(?:0[03-9]|2[02-5789]|[37]\d|4[02-69]|5[0-8]|[69][0-79]|8[0-5789])|5(?:0[1235-9]|2[024-9]|3[0145689]|4[02-9]|5[03-9]|6\d|7[0-35-9]|8[0-468]|9[0-5789])|6(?:0[034689]|2[0-689]|[38][013-9]|4[1-467]|5[0-69]|6[13-9]|7[0-8]|9[0124578])|7(?:0[0246-9]|2\d|3[023678]|4[03-9]|5[0-46-9]|6[013-9]|7[0-35-9]|8[024-9]|9[02-9])|8(?:0[35-9]|2[1-5789]|3[02-578]|4[0-578]|5[124-9]|6[2-69]|7\d|8[02-9]|9[02569])|9(?:0[02-589]|2[02-689]|3[1-5789]|4[2-9]|5[0-579]|6[234789]|7[0124578]|8\d|9[2-57]))\d{6}|1(?:2(?:0(?:46[1-4]|87[2-9])|545[1-79]|76(?:2\d|3[1-8]|6[1-6])|9(?:7(?:2[0-4]|3[2-5])|8(?:2[2-8]|7[0-4789]|8[345])))|3(?:638[2-5]|647[23]|8(?:47[04-9]|64[015789]))|4(?:044[1-7]|20(?:2[23]|8\d)|6(?:0(?:30|5[2-57]|6[1-8]|7[2-8])|140)|8(?:052|87[123]))|5(?:24(?:3[2-79]|6\d)|276\d|6(?:26[06-9]|686))|6(?:06(?:4\d|7[4-79])|295[567]|35[34]\d|47(?:24|61)|59(?:5[08]|6[67]|74)|955[0-4])|7(?:26(?:6[13-9]|7[0-7])|442\d|50(?:2[0-3]|[3-68]2|76))|8(?:27[56]\d|37(?:5[2-5]|8[239])|84(?:3[2-58]))|9(?:0(?:0(?:6[1-8]|85)|52\d)|3583|4(?:66[1-8]|9(?:2[01]|81))|63(?:23|3[1-4])|9561))\d{3}|176888[234678]\d{2}|16977[23]\d{3}|7(?:[1-4]\d\d|5(?:0[0-8]|[13-9]\d|2[0-35-9])|624|7(?:0[1-9]|[1-7]\d|8[02-9]|9[0-689])|8(?:[014-9]\d|[23][0-8])|9(?:[04-9]\d|1[02-9]|2[0-35-9]|3[0-689]))\d{6}|76(?:0[012]|2[356]|4[0134]|5[49]|6[0-369]|77|81|9[39])\d{6}|80(?:0\d{6,7}|8\d{7})|500\d{6}|(?:87[123]|9(?:[01]\d|8[0-3]))\d{7}|8(?:4[2-5]|70)\d{7}|70\d{8}|56\d{8}|(?:3[0347]|55)\d{8}|8(?:001111|45464\d)$|(?:\((\+?\d+)?\)|(\+\d{0,3}))? ?\d{2,3}([-\.]?\d{2,3} ?){3,4}`
```

please dont bother about regex length.

It matches even if match length exceeds

What is missing to restrain it to filer 8-14 length pattern match only.

Comment: Wow........this kind of thing should be commented with the `x` modifier and `(?# ...)`.

Answer (score 5):

**First off,** `^(?=.{8,14})b$` means "at the beginning of the string as asserted by `^`, look ahead to see if we can find a single character between 8 and 14 times, and if yes, then match a single character `b` then the end of the line `$`. You cannot have one line that is both a single character `b` and 8 characters in length. **This part of the expression can never match.** [See demo](http://regex101.com/r/vH8hH9).

**But your regex still finds an overall match. Why?** Clearly, even if `^(?=.{8,14})b$` were able to match anything, it does not set a condition for the whole expression, because something later in the regex overrides it: an alternation (`|`) which means that we can match what's on the left **OR** what's on the right.

Comment: Doesn't quite answer the problem, but honestly don't think OP's problem warrants an answer. Good job at explaining the why it didn't work though, +1.

Comment: thanks @zx81: for explainations. I believe, it is not possible with this regex to limit it between such range